# app registration required for windows apps in azure ad

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am trying to access a azure hosted service using the windows client. It is required to register the windows client with Azure AD and the get the application id for requesting the authentication token/sign-in.

For web apps this is not needed. The browser itself will automatically re-direct to the login page for authentication and the token is getting cached in the cookie.

Is it possible for the windows client to sign-in to the azure ad similar to web apps without needing to register itself?

Comment: web app also need to register with AAD. IN order to get the token, All applications need to register with AAD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Comment: they both have to be registered with azure ad. if you simply turned on azure ad on your web app it automatically registers and create service principle